# Mongoose error - Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined" a server error or a coding error ?
I am using rhel 64bit os. Its an application in nodejs and  mongodb with mongoose

I am also getting the below error in node application terminal when I try to access the webpage.

```
***********************************
   POST /users 500 161ms
   debug - client authorized
   info  - handshake authorized LrvFf3z-BowsuVlzS5tq
```

---

```
Restarting the node I get the below lines

*************************
  rs
7 Dec 04:00:04 - [nodemon] restarting child process
7 Dec 04:00:04 - [nodemon] exception in nodemon killing node
util.error: Use console.error instead
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:682:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:530:26)
7 Dec 04:00:04 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
   info  - socket.io started
Express app started on port 80
mongodb connected
```

---

Does any one you know what is wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the code that the error is pointing to?

Comment: Post your schema definitions.

Comment: I am using mean stack 

https://github.com/linnovate/mean

You can see the schema here. 

https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/app/models/user.js

Getting error on the following line of mongoose/lib/document.js

&& !(this.schema.paths[key] && this.schema.paths[key].options.ref) (line no. 449)

This is working fine in local. Only when I added it on AWS, this issue is coming. Mongodb is connected fine.